# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas. error while processing transactions

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc, out-of-gas

MY CONTRACT :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract TestContract{
    string coaf;
    string choice;
    string info;
    string isin;
    string recordDate;
    string exDate;

    function TestContract(string _coaf, string _choice, string _info,string _isin,string _recordDate,string _exdate){
        coaf = _coaf;
        choice = _choice;
        info = _info;
        isin =_isin;
        recordDate=_recordDate;
        exDate=_exdate;
    }


    function getFields() constant returns(string, string, string,string,string,string){
        return(coaf,choice,info,isin,recordDate,exDate);

    }
   function SetFields(string _coaf,string _choice,string _info,string _isin,string _recordDate,string _exdate){
     coaf=_coaf;
     choice=_choice;
     info=_info;
     isin=_isin;
     recordDate=_recordDate;
     exDate=_exdate;
   }
    function setChoice(string _choice) {
        info = _choice;
    }

}
```

MY CALL :

```
 TestContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    return instance.SetFields(coaf,choice,info,isin,exDate,recordDate,{gas:3000000},{from:web3.eth.accounts[1]});
  }).then(function(result) {
    save_th(result.tx,type);
    console.log("Transaction:", result.tx);
    console.log("Finished!");
    //done();
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  //done();
  });
```

MY DEPLOYMENT :

```
    var TestContract=artifacts.require('TestContract');
    module.exports = function(deployer) {
    // Pass 42 to the contract as the first constructor parameter
    deployer.deploy(TestContract,"Default","Default","Default","Default","Default","Default");
};
```

NEED URGENT HELP !!!!

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable. Where does your contract fail? Is it at deploy,or is it at calling a method? Where are you testing? Is it at a private testnet, or testnet or mainnet? Processing string is expensive you can try increasing the gas passed to deployment and transactions.

Comment: Its when i call the method set fields. I  increased the gas limit nothing works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many strings? Strings a very expensive in the EVM. Try bytes or try to avoid strings. I had similar problems with my dApp and Smart Contract. I removed all strings (thus redesigned) and now all works just fine.

Comment: one more thing: also if you have typ problems, e.g. the input type (when calling the function) is not string, this error can occur. I would also check this. Also had that quite often, even though I though types were correct, they weren't. If you are used to programming in Eclipse or so, you might get a warning from the IDE. Here, you don't (if you are just using web web3 console for example)

Comment: If you're using testrpc, do a $ truffle migrate --reset. It's normal for the blockchain to loose the deployed contracts when you restart truffle.

Comment: this may be a noob question but will bytes be able to handle the string inputs ?

Comment: hmmm, your contract definitely works fine. I tried it in Remix.

Comment: Just go to http://remix.ethereum.org/

copy and paste your code,
select environment "JavaScript VM", create a instance of your contract, then use the funciton "SetFields"...you will see it works. Thus, your deployment and/or call function might be the reason. Remix gives you nice deploy code (see field "Web3 deploy").

In Geth (I assume you are using it), simply call the function with _contractObject_.SetFields(...)

Thus, the string stuff might be a problem, but not the major reason here. The function "SetFields" gas costs are:
Transaction cost: 91182 gas. 
Execution cost: 63958 gas.

Comment: @StefanRichter So i am getting the same out of gas error when i try to execute a transaction with parameters as : bytes32 and uint votes